# Stream to Discord using OBS?

Tags: streaming

I would like to know if it's possible to stream video on discord using OBS instead of the built in screen share module in discord.

Any tips?

Answer (score 14):

I found how:

Inside OBS, right click the preview canvas and select `Windowed projector (Preview)`. Then, ask Discord to screen share that window.